# Symfony and PHPExcel (with React.js), not downloading

Tags: javascript, symfony, reactjs, phpexcel

I'm using liuggio/ExcelBundle, this is my code to write and download the xlsx:

```
    $writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel2007');
    $response = $this->get('phpexcel')->createStreamedResponse($writer);
    $dispositionHeader = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        'XXX_-_' . ( new \DateTime() )->format( 'Y_n_j' ) . '.xlsx'
    );
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'maxage=1');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $dispositionHeader);
```

When I call the method directly from a React component it download ok:

```
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = path.url_descarga_excel;
    $.UIkit.init();
```

But I need to pass some arguments. When I try to download with AJAX:

```
    e.preventDefault();

    var sist_electrico = {
        sic: ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.SIC).checked,
        sing: ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.SING).checked 
    };

    var periodo = {
        inicio: this.refs.fechaInicio.getValue(),
        fin: this.refs.fechaFin.getValue() 
    };

    var form = $('input[name="radio_tipoForm"]:checked').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:path.url_descarga_excel, async:false,
        type:"post", dataType:"json", data:{form, sist_electrico, periodo},
    });
```

it doens't download, it just show the characters of the file in the preview of Chrome:

Preview:

```
    PK�QI%���a[Content_Types].xml͔]K�0���%��f� "�v��R... etc
```

Headers:

```
    Request URL:http://XXX/app_dev.php/reporte/descargaExcel
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:200 OK
    Response Headers
    view source
    Cache-Control:maxage=1, private
    Connection:Keep-Alive
    Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="XXX.xlsx"
    Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8
    Date:Thu, 11 Aug 2016 14:15:50 GMT
    Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
    Server:Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.4.45
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked
    X-Debug-Token:ea66a8
    X-Debug-Token-Link:/app_dev.php/_profiler/ea66a8
    X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.45
    Request Headers
    view source
    Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8
    Cache-Control:no-cache
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:108
    Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    Cookie:PHPSESSID=m6tcoofak8ihe02nit0nj7lj85
    Host:cnecontrato.adevcom.cl
    Origin:XXX
    Pragma:no-cache
    Referer:http://XXX/app_dev.php
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
    X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I also use $writer->save('php://output'); at the end of the code, but the only difference is this: http://fotos.subefotos.com/69cda253c4e362862c62b6702e048127o.png

Comment: I've just read that is not possible to download files though ajax calls due javascript security, don't know how to pass those arguments and download the file, can't see help for that. All that people suggest is to use window.location to open the onClick in another window but that's not my case...

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I just did this:

```
exportarExcel:function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var sist_electrico = {
        sic: ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.SIC).checked,
        sing: ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.SING).checked 
    };

    var periodo = {
        inicio: this.refs.fechaInicio.getValue(),
        fin: this.refs.fechaFin.getValue() 
    };

    var form = $('input[name="radio_tipoForm"]:checked').val();

    location.href = path.url_descarga_excel + "?form=" + form + "&sist_electrico=" + sist_electrico + "&periodo=" + periodo;
    $.UIkit.init();
```

the old location.href with parameters. Now the PHP is receiving the parameters and the xlsx is being downloaded correctly.